# Code bundled with PyInstaller cannot import a locally installed vtk module: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pyinstaller, vtk

I tried to apply pyinstaller to the simple file vtest.py

```
import vtk

print('Hello World')
```

on windows. I can run the command

```
py vtest.py
```

without issue. But when I try to generate an exe with the command

```
pyinstaller vtest.py --onefile
```

I get the error when I try to run the executable

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vtest.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\djame\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "vtk.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkmodules'
[11448] Failed to execute script vtest
```

I tried changing the hook file as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835851/python-executable-with-vtk-pyinstaller-py2exe-cx-freeze-etc/21852342#21852342) but no luck.

Comment: When not using pyinstaller can you import vtkmodules? If you can, could you please post here its `vtkmodules.__file__`. In case `python3 -c "import vtkmodules as v; print(v.__file__)"` fails: you can edit vtk.py line 30 to print `vitmoudles.__file__`

Comment: Also, can you please add `import vtkmodules` anywhere in your main code and retry building and running? Does it help?

Comment: I can import vtkmodules. When I print vtkmodules.__file__ I get `C:\Users\djame\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vtkmodules\__init__.py`

Comment: I have tried adding `import vtkmodules` in my code and it generates a similar error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vtkmodules.all'`. When I then import vtkmodules.all, it seems to work!!

Comment: Ok, I posted the answer, also I'll edit the title now, so people with the same problem can find it with google

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pyinstaller can't detect this import so it doesn't attach it to the bundle. This happens due to less straightforward imports in the libs.

There are more than one solution:

- Anywhere in your code add `import` statement for every missing module. As adding new module might lead to new missing modules it imports, you might need several iterations.
- Add the same list of modules to `hiddenimports` argument in [spec file](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-operation) or console command. This process might be iterative as well.

Another reason for missing modules is that PyInstaller treats them as system ones, because they are stored in dirs like `/usr/lib`. You can check if it is your case by importing the module and printing its `.__file__`.